# What does my_string(char* s) mean?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, stringstream

Please tell me what does the parameter (char* s) means?? Can it accept an array of characters or it will just accept pointers. Please also tell how can i make this to accept an array of strings and then dynamically assign memory depending on the length of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, it's a pointer to a single `char` variable. However, it can also be the pointer to the first element of an *array* of `char` values. You can increment and decrement the pointer to move through the string (`s++` or `s--`) as long as you don't go beyond the ends.

You can also use indexing without changing the pointer, such as `s[14] = 'a';`.

Using it as a pointer to a `char` array is usually the case when you're dealing with C-style strings.

In addition, a `char` array will decay to the pointer to its first element under many circumstances, such as passing to a function:

```
void fn (char *s) {
    printf ("%s\n", s);
}
:
char xyz[50];
strcpy (xyz, "Hello");
fn (xyz);
```

For an array of strings in C, you would use `char **`, a pointer to and array of `char` pointers.

For C++, you should probably ditch `char` pointers (for strings) and pass-by-pointer altogether. Use `std::string` and reference types.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i make this to accept an array of strings

C++ solution:

```
void foo(std::vector<std::string> const& strings);
```

C solution:

```
void foo(const char **strings);
```

Answer (score 0):

char* s means that s is a pointer to a memory location where characters are stored. Yes, it will accept arrays of characters, such in this example:

```
void func(char* s)
{
}

int main()
{
  char arr[10] = {0};

  func(arr);

  return 0;
}
```

To answer how to make it to accept an array of strings, please tell what you understand by strings. Is it the std::string class, or char*?

Answer (score 0):

`char* s` means that `s` is **pointing** to a single `char` variable or to an array of `char`'s (better known as char pointer). Also to add, a string is basically an array of `char`s.

To pass a char array to a method that accepts char pointer and/or array of chars, you can do something like this:

```
void foo(const char** string) {

}

int main() {
    char[] s = "My String";
    foo(&s);
}
```

Comment: @Elite, that should be `foo(&s)`, no?